# Elementary differential equations: $(xy)y' + (2xy)^2 = 3x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the elementary differential equation of order 1 $$(xy)y' + (2xy)^2 = 3x$$ 
I have tried to solve it using Exact and even seperable method but all to no avail, I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by dividing your ODE by $xy$:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+4x y=\frac{3}{y} \tag{1}$$
Notice that this is a [Bernoulli ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Bernoulli.aspx) because it is in the form:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n \tag{2}$$
It is well known that the substitution $v=y^{1-n}$ converts $(2)$ into a linear ODE. Hence, in your case, we substitute $v=y^2$. From the chain rule, we know that $\frac{dv}{dx}=2y\frac{dy}{dx}$. Rewriting $(1)$ conveniently:
$$\color{green}{2y\frac{dy}{dx}}+8x\color{blue}{y^2}=6$$
Substituting gives the [linear ODE](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx) we wanted:
$$\color{green}{\frac{dv}{dx}}+8x\color{blue}{v}=6 \tag{3}$$
Equation $(3)$ can be solved using the integrating factor method. The general solution will have to be in terms of non-elementary functions since you will at one point have to evaluate $\int e^{4x^2}~dx$.

Comment: please evaluate \int e^{4x^2}~dx

Comment: @LogicalOgbonna Substitute $u=2x$ and apply the definition of the [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function). This will give:
$$\int e^{4x^2}~dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\operatorname{erfi}(2x)+C$$

Answer (score 1):

$$(xy)y' + (2xy)^2 = 3x \quad\to\quad 2yy'+8xy^2=6$$
Change of function $\quad Y=y^2 \quad\to\quad Y'+8xY=6\quad$ is a non-homogeneous linear ODE.

The associated homogeneous linear ODE $\quad Y_h'+8xY_h=0\quad$ is easy to solve :
$$Y_h=C\:e^{-4x^2}$$
With the method of variation of parameter, the solution of the non-homogeneous ODE is searched on the form $Y=C(x)e^{-4x^2}$ where $C$ is non longer a constant.

$Y'+8xY=C'e^{-4x^2}-8Cxe^{-4x^2}+8xCe^{-4x^2}=C'e^{-4x^2}=6$

$C'=6e^{4x^2}\quad\to\quad C(x)=6\int e^{4x^2}dx\quad\to\quad Y(x)=6e^{-4x^2}\int e^{4x^2}dx$

The integral cannot expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. If you know the special function erfi :
$\quad \int e^{4x^2}dx=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{\pi}\text{erfi}(2x)+c$

You have the choice :

- Let it with the indefinite integral : $\quad y(x)=\pm  \sqrt{6e^{-4x^2}\int e^{4x^2}dx}$
- Use the special function erfi : $\quad y(x)=\pm e^{-2x^2} \sqrt{\frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\text{erfi}(2x)+c}$
- Express the solution on the form of infinite series (more arduous).

Note that an arbitrary constant is included in the indefinite integral.